# PHP: append span tag within a href anchor text

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying but I can't obtain which I need.
I'm validating my html to rich snippets, and I have this code:

```
<a href="http://www.xxxx.xxx/xxxxxxx" rel="tag">MY_ANCHOR_TEXT</a>
```

So **I need to append a span tag**, like:

```
<a href="http://www.xxxx.xxx/xxxxxxx" rel="tag"><span itemprop="title">MY_ANCHOR_TEXT</span></a>
```

I'm in wordpress, and I have:

```
$course_category = get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'course-cat', '', '', '' );
```

where $course_category contains the a tag above.

Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks, Daniel

EDIT1: I've tried by using:

```
$course_category = preg_replace( '/<a\shref=\".*\">(.+<\/a>)/', '<a><span itemprop="title">$1</span>', $course_category );
```

but I don't obtain what I need

Comment: Do you know preg_match of php? ;)

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far getting this done for your site?

Comment: I've tried 
$course_category = preg_replace( '/<a\shref=\".*\">(.+<\/a>)/', '<a><span itemprop="title">$1</span>', $course_category );

Comment: Where did you post this in your question? :) Would you dont mind posting complete information in your code. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest to you to make your own html generation loop:
Using  [get_the_terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) you can get all terms and then with 1 simple loop ( foreach ) you can generate your output.
I think it will be something as

```
  $slug = 'course-cat';
  $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $slug );

  if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
      echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term->slug, $slug ) .'" rel="tag"><span itemprop="title">' . $term->name . '</span></a>';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Wow! Wonderful! I'm going to try it :)